# How to tweet live data in database using twitter API

Tags: twitter

I have live data in a database i want to tweet data in real time
example live temperature , news , updates .

help me to get started.
As of now I have a site and I want to update the data in site as tweet.

Example :

10:15 GMT : Earthquake in China
10:16 GMT : tsunami Warning

the above is the data in a web site , I want to tweet it .

Help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to tweet you can use oAuth. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792892/1271632) has a link to the oAuth library and shows how to connect to the API. This [guide](http://www.davidxia.com/2011/07/how-to-write-a-program-that-tweets-automatically) shows how to make a tweet bot, but it also shows how to connect your db, and how to tweet as well. Use for examples etc